# Are there real vectors (one-dimensional arrays) in Perl?

Tags: c, performance, perl, vector, malloc

I know that traditional "lists" in Perl implemented internally exactly as a real double-linked lists. So indexed access to the list elements is slow. This is a cost of dynamic nature of lists, which can be sliced, expanded, shrinked.

But for performance reasons it will be very good to have possibility to malloc() some memory chunk and create vector of static size and predefined size of its elements: for example, fixed-size double-linked list may be represented as a sequence of elements which size will be 4(prev_v_index) + 4(next_v_index) + 8(data_ptr aka REF) = 16 bytes. So we can access every element of this vector as we usually do it in compiled languages like C: elem_ptr=vector_ptr+(index*elem_size) - access to elements will be very fast with some architecure-specific alignment (8 bytes for x86_64).

Maybe there is already some XS module for manipulating with the fixed-vectors in Perl5?

Comment: @GerhardBarnhard: Please don't remove useful tags from questions

Comment: It sounds like you are making wild guesses about Perl internals. Perl doesn't use linked lists at all. Have you profiled your program and found array access to be a bottleneck? I very much doubt it.

Comment: So... Are there implementations of pre-allocated static arrays for Perl? I.e. arrays without ANY dynamic logic, strong boundaries checking and with standard indexed access methods?

Comment: I would be very surprised if you need them. You certainly haven't shown any evidence that backs up your idea. Do you have any rational reason to pick on array access?

Comment: Re "*I know that traditional "lists" in Perl implemented internally exactly as a real double-linked lists.*", This is completely wrong. When we say a sub returns a list, it simply pushes a number of scalars on the stack (which is an array of array, not a linked list).

Comment: I understand, thank you. I was fooled by one "forums perl guru". I am very sorry for my stupid not verified assumptions :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl's arrays (`@array` variables or `[...]` references) do use a contiguous memory region. They are not linked lists. However, these arrays only hold pointers to the scalar values, not the values themselves. This is a necessary restriction of the Perl data model.

If you know C++, a Perl array can be thought of as similar to a `std::vector<Scalar*>`, except that Perl's arrays can push and pop at the front and the back.

To resize a Perl array, you can assign the last index. E.g. to pre-allocate 50 elements:

```
my @array;
$#array = 50 - 1;
```

If you need compact data storage within Perl, then you will have to use strings. Given a fixed-size record, you can get and set one record with `substr`, and `pack`/`unpack` the data from and to Perl data structures.

Comment: If perl arrays uses contiguos memory region - how works push'ing and splice'ing (removing elements from the middle) ot them? For example, if an array was created with 4K memory allocation and now it grows to 4000 bytes - how can we push, say, 200 bytes to that array?

Comment: @drvtiny It works just like vectors in  C++ or ArrayLists in Java: when the capacity is exceeded, new storage is allocated and the elements copied over. When an element is removed from the middle, the remaining elements are copied to a new location. The array should be though of as having four pointers: storage start <= contents_start <= contents_end <= storage end.

Comment: Strings is also dynamic structures: does perl will re-allocate another memory region and copies all string content to that new region on every expanding above the previously alocated chunk (mem region) size? And what is the default value for this default size?

Comment: @drvtiny: *"how can we push, say, 200 bytes to that array?"* You can work with bytes only by using Perl strings, which have an allowance of space beyond the end where a string can expand. If you run out of space altogether then the string is copied to a new, bigger area of memory before extending it. Why do you want to know this?

Comment: @drvtiny Yes, strings use the same approach. When the storage is resized it's typically doubled to the nearest power of two (i.e. exponentially). Because more storage is allocated than immediately needed, not every push/append will cause allocations and copies. In fact, this has provably O(1) amortized complexity. This is discussed thoroughly in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array

Comment: I was in doubt, whether using of fixed-size lists in Perl will lead to better peformance because of avoiding memory-reallocations. So... amon's answer as i can understand it is "yes, it is very good to use static-sized vectors and not to use splice/push without strong necessity".

Comment: @drvtiny Splicing in the *middle* causes all elements on the right to be shifted around. Splicing at the end or pushing is totally fine. You are not likely to write Perl programs where the cost of array resizing will have a measurable impact.

Comment: >You are not likely to write Perl programs where the cost of array resizing will have a measurable impact
Why do you think so? :)

Comment: @drvtiny: I would agree, because I have never found a Perl application where the speed of array manipulation was an issue. You don't say anything about your application, but you seem to be making random guesses. Originally you wanted a way of avoiding a linked list implementation because it would slow down random access; now you are saying you want mid-array `splice` operations to work fast as well. I am sure you have just read about this neat thing and want to implement it to make everyone to think you're really clever.

Comment: @drvtiny: I have good news: the most clever thing is to accept the advice of the Perl specialists that you've asked for.

Comment: Sorry, Borodin, but you make absolutely false assumptions. I dont make applications (ok, i do it, but very rarely), i write libraries to be used by other applications. This is a part my work and my hobby too. I think universal API/libraries must be pre-optimized. If this is a package implementing circle/ring buffer - with the fixed size and possibility to remove mid-elements from it - i think, it can be implemented with simplest StaticArray's, and its a pitty that there are no such datastructures in Perl.

Comment: @drvtiny Rules of optimization: 1) Don't. 2) Don't yet. 3) Profile first. It's possible that you need to worry about how perl implements arrays but it's _highly_ unlikely that you do. (If it really does matter for your particular task you should probably be writing XS code rather than pure Perl.)

Comment: @drvtiny, Re "*If perl arrays uses contiguos memory region - how works push'ing and splice'ing (removing elements from the middle) ot them?*", Removing elements from the middle requires shifting all preceding or following elements. Not efficient. /// Removing elements from the start is done by incrementing an offset, incrementing the pointer to the array buffer, decrementing the number of elements allocated, and decrementing the number of elements in the array. Very efficient. /// Removing elements at from the end is done by decrementing the number of elements in the array. Very efficient.

Comment: @drvtiny, Re "*how can we push, say, 200 bytes to that array?*", In C, an array is simply a reference to a memory area. In Perl, it's more like an object that contains a pointer to memory area. It also has things such as the number of elements allocated, and the total number of elements used. When more space is needed, the array buffer is re-allocated, usually with extra space to reduce the need for future re-allocations. Only the pointer to the array buffer may change in a re-allocation, not the pointer to the array "object", so references to the array aren't invalidated.

Comment: @drvtiny, Re "*Why do you think [I am not likely to write Perl programs where the cost of array resizing will have a measurable impact]? :)*", Because we've never heard of a program where it does. Because pushing is amortized O(1). [It's O(N) to push N]. Because it's cheap compared to sub calls. etc.

Comment: @amon, Re "*Splicing in the middle causes all elements on the right to be shifted around.*", Perl will shift the elements on the left if there are fewer of those.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `vec` function to use a string as a vector. For example, you could pack Boolean values into individual bits.

> vec EXPR,OFFSET,BITS
>
> Treats the string in EXPR as a bit vector made up of elements of
>   width BITS and returns the value of the element specified by
>   OFFSET as an unsigned integer. BITS therefore specifies the
>   number of bits that are reserved for each element in the bit
>   vector. This must be a power of two from 1 to 32 (or 64, if your
>   platform supports that).

That said, your concern about array access being "slow" is unwarranted and your beliefs about perl's internals is incorrect. Array performance is likely to be fast enough. Don't try to "optimize" around it until you've profiled your code and proven that its a bottleneck.